# After using dir() on a object, i only get some of the list of valid attributes from the object, the rest are displayed as [...]

Tags: python

After using `dir()` on a `object`, i only get some of the list of valid attributes from the object, the rest are displayed with `[...]` at the end

Is there a way to get all of them to show?

And example of output would be `[ '__class__', '__something__', '__something__', ...]`

But the output i want would be `[ '__class__', '__something__', '__something__', '__something__' 'names', 'numbers']`

Comment: what Repl are you using? are you using the default python interpreter from the cli?

Comment: `print(','.join(dir()))` should give the full output *whatever* you're using

Comment: Keep in mind that the result of `dir` may not be "complete". Objects can implement `__dir__` to customize the output and they can also define `__getattr__`, `__getattribute__` or `__setattr__` to customize attribtue access which cannot be automatically detected by `dir`.